# How to convert a pandas dataframe in to dictionary of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe from which i need to generate a dictionary in a very specific format.

This is how the dataframe looks like this:

```
              end_hour  start_hour  values
level_0 level_1         
FRIDAY  0   6   0   {'onDemandTripBase': 4.269,tripMoving': 1.086,tripWaiting': 17.375}
1   10  6   {'onDemandTripBase': 4.269,tripMoving': 1.086,tripWaiting': 17.375}
2   24  10  {'onDemandTripBase': 4.269,tripMoving': 1.086,tripWaiting': 17.375}
MONDAY  0   6   0   {'onDemandTripBase': 4.269,tripMoving': 1.086,tripWaiting': 17.375}
1   10  6   {'onDemandTripBase': 4.7,tripMoving': 1.2,tripWaiting': 19.1}
2   24  10  {'onDemandTripBase': 4.269,tripMoving': 1.086,tripWaiting': 17.375}
```

Using this, i need to generate a dict like this:

```
{'FRIDAY': [{'end_hour': 6,'start_hour': 0,'values':{'onDemandTripBase':4.269,'tripMoving': 1.086,'tripWaiting': 17.375}},
  {'end_hour': 10,
   'start_hour': 6,
   'values': {'onDemandTripBase': 4.7,
    'tripMoving': 1.2,
'tripWaiting': 19.1}},
  {'end_hour': 24,
   'start_hour': 10,
 'values': {'onDemandTripBase': 4.269,
'tripMoving': 1.086,
'tripWaiting': 17.375}}],
'MONDAY': [{'end_hour': 6,
  'start_hour': 0,
   'values': {'onDemandTripBase': 4.269,
'tripMoving': 1.086,
'tripWaiting': 17.375}},
  {'end_hour': 10,
   'start_hour': 6,
   'values': {'onDemandTripBase': 4.7,
    'tripMoving': 1.2,
    'tripWaiting': 19.1}},
  {'end_hour': 24,
   'start_hour': 10,
   'values': {'onDemandTripBase': 4.269,
    'tripMoving': 1.086,
'tripWaiting': 17.375}}]
```

I tried by setting multi index and then converting the dataframe to dict using .to_dict('index'), but that seems to create a tuple as a key. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to provide the input DataFrame as code to construct it

Comment: add the dataframe as code..thanks